# When we analyze company we invest in using cash flow, how is their buying real estate different from buying computers?

Tags: stocks, investing, cash-flow

When we invest our money in public companies, we may analyze them using cash flow.  There can be two different scenarios:

1. the company buys a lot of real estate or warehouses as their capital expenditure, and the real estate and warehouses hold their value over 30 or even 100 years, versus
2. the company buys computers or semiconductor manufacturing equipments as their capital expenditure, and the computers or equipments drops to 1/10 of their value or need to be sold as scrap metal in 10 or 20 years.

so if net income is $100 million, and capital expenditure is $50 million, and depreciation is $48 million for both companies above, wouldn't the cash flow be:

1. company 1: $100 million + $48 million = $148 million
2. company 2: $100 million + $48 million - $50 million = $98 million?

The reason is that for company 1, its capital expenditure doesn't "sink" close to $0 but hold its value -- and even goes up in value after 30 years.  Is this thinking correct or incorrect?

Comment: Cash flow is nothing to  do with depreciation... or capital expenditure... cash is cash. Unless you are trying to estimate the cash flow based on numbers that aren't the cash flow?

Comment: no, this is one definition of cash flow:  cash flow = net income + depreciation - capital expenditure, and it also has another name, called "owner's earning"

Comment: Cash flow is certainly not the same as "owner's earning". A company can be very profitable, but still lose cash.

Comment: Why did you only include the $50M capex on company 1?

Comment: @user253751 care to give an example? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Owner_earnings Owner earnings is a valuation method detailed by Warren Buffett in Berkshire Hathaway's annual report in 1986. He stated that the value of a company is simply the total of the net cash flows (owner earnings) expected to occur over the life of the business, minus any reinvestment of earnings.

Comment: @nonopolarity A company that spends all its profits on new equipment will have zero cash flow, because it has the same amount of cash it started with, but still have a profit because it is gaining equipment.

Comment: @user253751 please see updated comment above

Comment: @user253751 you said "A company that spends all its profits on new equipment will have zero cash flow, because it has the same amount of cash it started with, but still have a profit because it is gaining equipment" so you are saying profits = net income = $100m, and depreciation = $48m, and they spend $100m on equipment? then cash flow = $100m + $48m - $100m = $48m.  Perhaps your profits is not the same as net income

Comment: @nonopolarity depreciation isn't cash! Who put depreciation in the cash flow equation? And profits can include non-cash profit, like sales made this month even though the bill is only due next month. It goes in this month's profits but next month's cash flow.

Comment: @user253751 depreciation is a reduction to net income and must be "removed" (added back) to get to cash flow

Comment: @DStanley There are other net income reductions and increases, too, like the deferred payments I mentioned. Not only depreciation.

Comment: @user253751 True, but depreciation is often the largest one and was the focus of the question.

Comment: Real estate in commercial use is also depreciated. But real estate is renovated and so property-REIT's, for instance, often ignore depreciation to pay higher dividends but then they do, of course, account renovation costs. They call it funds-from-operations.

Answer (score 1):

The flaw in your logic is not recognizing the link between income, depreciation, and cash flow.

Depreciation is a non-cash expense. So if depreciation is higher for one company than another (all else being equal), then the net income will be lower due to the higher expense. It's added back to income to "back into" the total *cash* flow.  So adding back depreciation to get cash flow will cancel out the differences.

In other words, both companies would have the same amount of *cash* income and the same mount of *cash* expenses. Depreciation has no net effect on cash flow.

You could break `net income` into its cash and non-cash pieces and see that:

```
Cash flow = (cash income - depreciation) + depreciation + capex
```

Now it's clearer that depreciaton is cancelled out in cash flow. (There is a secondary tax effect but I'm purposely ignoring that since it isn't the heart of your question)

It also illustrates that one measure cannot be used in isolation. You can certainly recognize the differences in buying assets that have a long live versus assets that need to be replaced in 3-5 years, but cash flow may not be the place that those differences appear.

Comment: I said `cash flow = net income + depreciation - capital expenditure`, I did not say `cash flow = cash income + depreciation - capital expenditure`

Comment: @nonopolarity then what you said seems to be wrong?

Comment: @nonopolarity You were correct, and I split net income into "cash" and "non-cash" (depreciation) components to show that depreciation cancelled out. It's already included in net income and must be "taken out".

Comment: or maybe I shouldn't have said "cash flow = net income + depreciation" because we really do need to add the capital expenditure at the right.  But just that the asset of company keeps on going up, while for company 2, the asset keeps on going down, getting close to $0... so the value of the company is not just based on cash flow, but cash flow plus what assets belong to it

Comment: looking at cash flow is _one_ way to look at a company. Looking at assets is another. That's why I say that you can't look at one in isolation. You can generate cash with very few assets and can have lots of assets but no real cash flow.